# Custom WordPress theme using Bulma Framework, blog cards not aligning properly

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, content-management-system, themes, bulma

I am making a WordPress theme with the Bulma CSS framework. So far it's working nicely except my blog cards are not displaying quite right.

I need them to align vertically on a single line, they do this perfectly well in my practice html file, but moving it onto WordPress they sit on top of each other.

Open to suggestions, and still learning how WordPress works

Currently testing this on MAMP Pro server

here is my code:

```
    <?php 

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    //'posts_per_page' => 2, 
    );

    $blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($blogposts->have_posts()){
        $blogposts->the_post();

    ?>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-variable is-4">
                <div class="column is-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image"><!--Image container-->
                            <figure class="image"><!--The Image-->
                                <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>"/>
                            </figure>
                        </div><!--Close image container-->
                        <div class="card-content"><!--Container for blog card text-->
                            <div class="content"><!--blog title, excerpt and link to full article-->
                                <h3 class="post_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More</a>     
                            </div><!--close content-->
                        </div><!--Close card-content-->
                    </div><!--Close card-->
                </div><!--Close column -->
            </div><!--Close columns-->
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php } ?><!--close while loop-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it by moving

```
<?php 

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
//'posts_per_page' => 2, 
);

$blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($blogposts->have_posts()){
    $blogposts->the_post();

?>
```

into columns is-multiline...